# I am getting java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching found. Spring Boot soap client

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, ssl

I have bundled the private key and certificate in my keystore is there another configuration i am missing?

```
Alias name: payments
Creation date: 11 Jun,2020
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
Serial number: 5ede3324
Valid from: Mon Jun 08 14:46:28 CAT 2020 until: Tue Jun 08 14:46:28 CAT 2021
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 84:DF:D0:33:B9:50:23:93:D9:97:DD:30:04:A6:E0:74:0C:2C:D4:93
     SHA256: 9E:C4:52:E0:90:F5:A1:99:08:F2:6F:3F:FE:32:68:56:A1:B4:6A:9E:27:1C:19:FA:D4:CA:DC:C9:1F:74:16:63
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
Certificate[2]:
ST=Harare, C=ZW
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Mon Jun 08 16:40:49 CAT 2020 until: Fri Nov 25 16:40:49 CAT 2022
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: E8:54:F7:00:0D:38:00:50:DF:EF:76:B8:F6:03:87:D7:8D:55:05:3D
     SHA256: B1:99:8D:1E:8C:AC:8A:74:84:E2:7F:4E:6C:55:EC:5F:82:8B:60:9D:DB:DE:94:18:A1:D7:FB:19:0F:5F:D7:08
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1
```

Comment: Any help here guys??